# Postgres правило для обновления представления?

Tags: sql, postgresql

Нашел справочный пример http://wiki.dandascalescu.com/howtos/how_to_update_postgresql_views

В нем описано как привязать правило на один определенный столбец, а возможно ли создать правило для всех столбцов представления?

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые вопросы. Поясните, в чем именно вы видите проблему, как её воспроизвести, что вы хотите получить в результате и т. д.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

вот нашел нормальный пример
https://vibhorkumar.wordpress.com/2011/10/28/instead-of-trigger/

если коротко, то нужно все колоки для всех таблиц из представления указывать отдельно в правиле

> исходные данные

```
CREATE TABLE person_detail(pid NUMERIC PRIMARY KEY, pname TEXT);
CREATE TABLE person_job(pid NUMERIC PRIMARY KEY references person_detail(pid), job TEXT);

INSERT INTO person_detail VALUES(1,'Angela');
INSERT INTO person_detail VALUES(2,'Tom');
INSERT INTO person_detail VALUES(3,'Heikki');

INSERT INTO person_job VALUES(1,'Documenter');
INSERT INTO person_job VALUES(2,'Developer');
INSERT INTO person_job VALUES(3,'Commiter');

CREATE VIEW person_detail_job_vw AS SELECT p.pid, p.pname, j.job FROM person_detail p LEFT JOIN person_job j ON (j.pid=p.pid);

SELECT * FROM person_detail_job_vw;
 pid | pname  |    job
-----+--------+------------
   1 | Angela | Documenter
   2 | Tom    | Developer
   3 | Heikki | Commiter
```

> создаем правило

```
CREATE RULE person_detaik_job_vw_UPDATE AS ON UPDATE TO person_detail_job_vw DO INSTEAD (
    UPDATE person_detail SET pid=NEW.pid, pname=NEW.pname WHERE pid=OLD.pid;
    UPDATE person_job SET pid=NEW.pid, job=NEW.job WHERE pid=OLD.pid
);
```

> проверяем

```
UPDATE person_detail_job_vw SET job='PATCHER'  WHERE pid=4;
UPDATE 1

SELECT * FROM person_detail_job_vw;
 pid | pname  |    job
-----+--------+------------
   1 | Angela | Documenter
   2 | Tom    | Developer
   3 | Heikki | Commiter
   4 | Singh  | PATCHER
```